# break point doesn't work!

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, breakpoints

I am working a network programming using eclipse CDT. It worked fine before if I set up a break point then it stops at that point. I don't know what happened, it doesn't work anymore. Even if I set up a break point, it won't stop.

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Maybe you are using a conditional breakpoint? Have you are error message? Have you checked the eclipse log?

Comment: Please post some code, the log, a screenshot... any additional information that will help people answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're running the application in debug mode? In run mode, the virtual machine will not suspend the thread on breakpoints.